# Cucumber: How to avoid ambiguous steps?

Tags: cucumber

I was creating 2 simple scenarios as follow:

```
Scenario: 1
Given I am on the homepage
When I click the expand arrow
Then the drawer is expanded

Scenario: 2
Given the drawer is expanded
```

and the problem is that the THEN of the 1st scenario and the GIVEN of the 2nd are written like this by cucumber:

```
Then /^the drawer is expanded$/ do
Given /^the drawer is expanded$/ do
```

and then I get an error message with:

```
Ambiguous match of "the drawer is expanded"
```

when I try to run it.

Is there a way to avoid this ambiguous steps?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best to rewrite the steps so that the two steps are different.

One way to do it would be to follow Pat Maddox's suggestion in his [Rewriting Ambiguous Cucumber Steps](http://patmaddox.com/2010/10/26/rewriting-ambiguous-cucumber-steps/) blogpost, and rewrite the second scenario as follows:

```
Scenario 2
Given that the drawer is expanded
```